# C program printf char with string array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char world[] = "HelloProgrammingWorld";
int main()
{
    printf("%s", world + world[6] - world[8]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be mmingWorld.

I knew the "world" will be store in memory something like this.

```
0x6295616             H    world[0]
0x6295617             e
0x6295618             l
0x6295619             l
0x6295620             o
0x6295621             P
0x6295622             r    world[6]
0x6295623             o
0x6295624             g    world[8]
0x6295625             r
0x6295626             a
0x6295627             m
0x6295628             m
0x6295629             i
0x6295630             n
0x6295631             g
0x6295632             W
0x6295633             o
0x6295634             r
0x6295635             l
0x6295636             d
```

But what is the formula to calculate the output to "mmingWorld". I had try several method and still cannot reach that word.

I compile using this https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Comment: `world[6] = 'r'` and `world[8] = 'g'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "formula".  It's just counting letters.  The string you want starts 11 characters into the array, so you want `world+11`.

Comment: @DanielWalker `world[6] - world[8]` (aka `'r' - 'g'`) is 11, not 2.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking.  I was thinking about `&world[6] - &world[8]`.

Comment: `'r' - 'g' == 11` [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @DanielWalker that would still not be 2, it would be *undefined* (out of bounds). `&world[8] - &world[6]` would be 2.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm tired and haven't had dinner yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`world[6]` is the character `'r'` in the string, and `world[8]` is the character `'g'` in the string.  In ASCII, `'r'` has a numeric value of 114, and `'g'` has a numeric value of 103.

When you refer to a fixed array by name, it *decays* into a pointer to the 1st element of the array.

So, you are basically taking a `char*` pointer to the 1st character in the string, and using **pointer arithmetic** to advance that pointer forward `114 - 103 = 11` number of characters in the string.  Thus you are effectively passing `&world[11]` to `printf()`, hense the output `"mmingWorld"`.